# How can I get SSID of my device on Android?

Tags: android, ssid

I want to get SSID of my device and I am using below code:

```
private void getSSID() throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    Method[] methods = wifiManager.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
    for (Method m: methods) {
        if (m.getName().equals("getWifiApConfiguration")) {
            WifiConfiguration config = (WifiConfiguration)m.invoke(wifiManager);
            String ssid = config.SSID;
            String bssid = config.BSSID;
            Log.d(TAG, "getSSID: " + ssid);
            Log.d(TAG, "getSSID: " + bssid);
        }
    }
}
```

But it is not working and giving null value.

Comment: what's your device veresion?

Comment: Version of my device is pie and 28 api

Answer (score 0):

> Try the below code and remember it if you are using android 7.0+ you have to turn on gps

```
private void getSSID(){
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService 
                   (Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
     WifiInfo info = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo ();
     String ssid  = info.getSSID();
}
```

Comment: sir  action ? What is action here?

Comment: sorry,.. in my code it the function was called from previous one.. lets edit and make simple for you

Comment: and of course add coarse location and fine location access in your manifest

Comment: do you enable gps.. and add permissions in manifest.. and turn on location permission from settings(android device) and try it

Comment: sir i have already enable gps and add all required permission but still not working

Answer (score 0):

You can get SSID as following

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService (Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo info = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo ();
String ssid  = info.getSSID();
```

From android 8.0 onwards we wont be getting SSID of the connected network unless GPS is turned on.

Comment: i have enabled gps then after that ssid is  =  <unknown ssid>

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiInfo info = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
    String ssid  = info.getSSID();
    String bssid = info.getBSSID();
```

add these permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

**since android 8 required coarse location permission**

Comment: in android 9 you have to turn on location @kam1234

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String getCurrentSSID(Context context) throws Exception {
    try {
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
        return wifiInfo.getSSID();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("Unable to read SSID");
    }
}
```

Just do not forget to add necessary permissions to the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```